# Angular2 : Iterate *ngfor particular times [ Error: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. ]

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to iterate a for loop for specific times ( angular 2.0.0-rc.4 ) . For ex. 5 times or 10 times..

**home.component.html :**

```
   {{arr_length}} //printing 10 i.e. I have specified in home.component.ts

        <tr *ngFor="let i of arr_length ; let ind = index">
            <td>
               //code goes here...
            </td>
        </tr>
```

But in ***ngFor** it throws error : `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

I am a newbie in angular. Any help would be appreciated.

**home.component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: '../templates/home.component.html',
  directives: [],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeComponent
{
    arr_length: number;
    constructor() 
    {
        this.arr_length = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: let us see  your components code. home.component.ts

Comment: The answer to your question is right in the text of the error.

Comment: @Casey: when I use an array then it works fine But how can I iterate for particular times ( Ex. 10 or 15 ) without using any array?

Comment: @Que : I have included home.component.ts code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over a number. I think you want to iterate over the array so from your component change your binding to just the array of your elements not there length.
If you want to loop just for n times.
the you could create array of n numbers. and loop over that array.
here is example to loop 10x 
On your component :

```
 export class HomeComponent
    {
        arr_length;
        constructor() 
        {
            this.arr_length = Array(10).fill().map((x,i)=>i);;
        }
    }
```

On your template

```
 <tr *ngFor="#number of arr_length">
       <td>
            //code goes here...
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes If I iterate over an array then it is working fine. But suppose I want to iterate for a particular number without taking help of any array then how can I do that?

Comment: yes this is working. Thank you. But can you explain the code inside constructor().

Comment: @vedu : in the constructor here is what what is going on:
1 - created empty array of size 10 --> Array(10)
2- fill it with numbers of the array index that is the fill() call and 
3- the map() operator maps indexes of the array to fill the elements

Comment: Ohh.. great. Thank you once again for that explanation.